# slice not working inside loop function in jquery

Tags: jquery

Using`slice(0,5)` does not slice the data, it displays all the rows.

```js
var search_value = $(this).val();
$('#data tr').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(search_value.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
    $(this).slice(0, 5).show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Are the elements hidden by default?

Comment: Just a hint for the future: don't do the same steps over and over again. Store `$(this)` in a variable if you need it more than once so you don't create multiple jQuery objects. Also do the `search_value.toUpperCase()` once (`var search_value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();`) instead of once per row because it doesn't change in the `.each()`.

Comment: by default there are 35 rows displayed, after i filter(search), it shows 10 rows but i want to display only 5 rows and next 5 rows on next page( pagination)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way for your feature will be the [filter() function](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) of jQuery.

```js
var $rows = $('#data tr');

function refreshTable(searchValue) {
  $rows
    .hide()
    .filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) > -1
    })
    .slice(0, 5)
    .show();
}

$('#search').on('keyup', function() {
  refreshTable($(this).val().toLowerCase());
});

refreshTable('');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" name="search" id="search" value="" />

<table id="data">
  <tr><td>01</td></tr>
  <tr><td>02</td></tr>
  <tr><td>03</td></tr>
  <tr><td>04</td></tr>
  <tr><td>05</td></tr>
  <tr><td>06</td></tr>
  <tr><td>07</td></tr>
  <tr><td>08</td></tr>
  <tr><td>09</td></tr>
  <tr><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>11</td></tr>
  <tr><td>12</td></tr>
  <tr><td>13</td></tr>
  <tr><td>14</td></tr>
  <tr><td>15</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You might want to "debounce" or "throttle" the `keyup` event handler. With a huge table, a fast writing style or a slow/busy browser this might end with a choppy behavior.